# How to inject config properties inside a Quarkus extension

Tags: java, quarkus, supersonic

I'm trying to move the following (working) code to an extension:

```
@WebListener
public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE")
    String projectStage;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        sce.getServletContext().setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", projectStage);
    }

}
```

When I move this code to an extension `runtime` module the property is not resolved (it is null).

The extension source code can be [found here](https://github.com/tandraschko/quarkus-myfaces/blob/5d73e8a3cac9fd73be54d2c68a35afc672c369f6/quarkus-myfaces/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/myfaces/runtime/startup/QuarkusServletContextListener.java#L30).

Comment: I'll let other answer the core of the question but this property should really be read at build time. The project stage is well mapped with our notion of dev / test / prod and the notion of configuration profile.
This should be read at build time and injected to the framework as part of the build time bootstrap approach instead of being a runtime property e.g. with https://quarkus.io/guides/extension-authors-guide#bytecode-recording

Comment: Yes, agreed, it will be nice to have javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE aligned with Quarkus stage so user doesn't even need to add an entry in application.properties (unless one wants to override the default stage behaviour)

Comment: You mean something like this @EmmanuelBernard?
https://github.com/rmpestano/quarkus-myfaces/blob/90a779b0fc34b38867647f219c583c99d8912e3a/quarkus-myfaces/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/myfaces/deployment/MyFacesProcessor.java#L197-L203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to make it work programatically via config provider:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    Config config = ConfigProvider.getConfig();
    String projectStage = config.getValue("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", String.class);
    sce.getServletContext().setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", projectStage);
}
```